# What can I do to make the screen look more realistic in a mockup photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, mockup

[image: What I have now][image: rough shadow application attempt]

The first photo is without photoshop. Pure Green Screen. 
The second is a rough attempt at adding shadows.

Both of these images look photoshopped. How can I make them look realistic?

Edit: So something like this?[image: Attempt 3]

Comment: Use a real photo. (Which, mind you, is not an absolute guarantee *against* ["it looks Photoshopped"](https://xkcd.com/331/).)

Comment: Everything except the screen is real

Comment: You need to blur the picture on the screen as much as the background. Right now it's twice as sharp. Alternatively, use a better background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a better photograph to begin with.  When editing photographs, there's an age-old adage that applies: *You can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear*.

The photograph of the phone, hand and table is very poor quality. It looks like you used a phone camera to take it. It's blurry, noisy, out of focus, the lighting is poor, and the white balance isn't right. Then it looks like you inserted a much better quality photograph into the phone photograph. That's what makes it look out of place.

If you can't take good photos yourself, then buy a stock photo, or hire a photographer, or find a friend with a real camera and some skill in photography and lighting.

Comment: Same sentiment, yet far more eloquent than my brief comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Late addition:

Your new version with grey backround is not much better. It is like a grey plane with a framed hole in front of green plants, there's no separate phone body.

This can be more like the wanted one:

[image]

- the phone is lifted up with a shadow and making it a little colored, the background is grey, actually it's very mild gradient
- the phone body is a drawing (=rounded rectangle, embossed to metallic) because I haven't sharp enough photo. A high resolution photo of a real thing would be much better. This is seen straight on the face, perspective would be useful. One is inserted to the end.
- the screen image has got contrast and saturation boost, the new frame tolerates it well
- there's a reflection in the glass. It's  a high contrast BW photo, warped a little to obscure lines which were too parallel with the frame. It has low opacity and blending mode ADD because the black parts must not make the screen image darker, only light parts of the reflection add something to the image.

**Perspective version.** The body of the phone is still only a drawing (=a rounded extruded rectangle, elementary non-photorealistic rendering).

[image]

The far end of the glass reflects more due the more gentle angle. That's simulated with layer mask.